Generando un archivo HTML desde PYTHON
estoy trabajando en este código que realiza un análisis léxico a la entrada del usuario, esa parte funciona correctamente, pero también estoy haciendo que se imprima el input del usuario en un archivo HTML, y las letras estén coloreadas de un color especifico dependiendo del tipo de carácter que es, el problema aquí radica en que los operadores binarios (+ - * /) así como los mismos paréntesis () o los signos de =, o hasta las comas, no se imprimen en el HTML, cual podría ser la causa de esto y cuales serian algunas posibles soluciones?
Adjunto el código
import sys

# Definición de tokens
INT = 100  # Número entero
FLT = 101  # Número de punto flotante
OPB = 102  # Operador binario
LRP = 103  # Delimitador: paréntesis izquierdo
RRP = 104  # Delimitador: paréntesis derecho
END = 105  # Fin de la entrada
COM = 106  # Separador coma ,
IDE = 107  # Identificador
ASI = 108  # Operador de Asignacion
ERR = 200  # Error léxico: palabra desconocida
#SYM = 109  # Símbolo

# Matriz de transiciones
MT = [[1, OPB, LRP, RRP, 4, 0, 4, END, COM, 5, ASI, ERR],  # edo 0 - estado inicial
      [1, INT, INT, INT, 4, INT, 2, INT, INT, 4, ASI, ERR],  # edo 1 - dígitos enteros
      [3, 4, 4, 4, 4, ERR, 4, 4, 4, 4, ASI, FLT],  # edo 2 - primer decimal flotante
      [3, FLT, FLT, FLT, 4, FLT, 4, FLT, FLT, 4, ASI, FLT],  # edo 3 - decimales restantes flotante
      [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, ERR, 4, 4, ERR, 4, 4, 4],  # edo 4 - estado de error
      [5, OPB, IDE, IDE, 4, IDE, END, 5, IDE, 5, ASI, IDE]]  # edo 5 - Identificadores

# Filtro de caracteres
def filtro(c):
    if c.isdigit():  # dígitos
        return 0
    elif c in "+-*/":  # operadores
        return 1
    elif c == '(':  # delimitador (
        return 2
    elif c == ')':  # delimitador )
        return 3
    elif c in (' ', '\t', '\n', '\r'):  # blancos
        return 5
    elif c == '.':  # punto
        return 6
    elif c == '$':  # fin de entrada
        return 7
    elif c == ',':  # coma
        return 8
    elif c.isalpha() or c == '_':  # letras e identificadores
        return 9
    elif c == "=":  # igual
        return 10
    else:  # caracter raro
        return 12

# Función para escribir un token con su clase CSS en HTML
def escribir_token(token, clase, archivo):
    archivo.write(f'<span class="{clase}">{token}</span>')

# Función principal: implementa el análisis léxico
def scanner():
    edo = 0  # número de estado en el autómata
    lexema = ""  # palabra que genera el token
    tokens = []
    leer = True  # indica si se requiere leer un caracter de la entrada estándar

    while True:
        while edo < 100:  # mientras el estado no sea ACEPTOR ni ERROR
            if leer:
                c = sys.stdin.read(1)
            else:
                leer = True
            edo = MT[edo][filtro(c)]
            if edo < 100 and edo != 0:
                lexema += c

        # Lista de errores
        if edo == INT:
            leer = False
            tokens.append((lexema, 'token-blue'))
        elif edo == FLT:
            leer = False
            tokens.append((lexema, 'token-green'))
        elif edo == OPB:
            tokens.append((lexema, 'token-purple'))
        elif edo == LRP:
            tokens.append((lexema, 'token-orange'))
        elif edo == RRP:
            tokens.append((lexema, 'token-orange'))
        elif edo == COM:
            tokens.append((lexema, 'token-brown'))
        elif edo == IDE:
            leer = False
            tokens.append((lexema, 'token-black'))
        elif edo == ASI:
            tokens.append((lexema, 'token-red'))
        elif edo == ERR:
            leer = False
            tokens.append((lexema, 'token-red'))
        if edo == END:
            return tokens
        lexema = ""
        edo = 0

# Función para generar el HTML con los tokens usando clases CSS
def generar_html(tokens):
    with open("output4.html", "w") as f:
        f.write('<html><head><title>Tokenización</title>')
        f.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">')
        f.write('</head><body>')
        for token, clase in tokens:
            escribir_token(token, clase, f)
            f.write(' ')
        f.write('</body></html>')

tokens = scanner()
generar_html(tokens)

El código del archivo css es muy básico pero aquí lo adjunto también por cualquier cosa
/* estilos.css */

.token-blue {
    color: blue;
}

.token-green {
    color: green;
}

.token-purple {
    color: purple;
}

.token-orange {
    color: orange;
}

.token-brown {
    color: brown;
}

.token-black {
    color: black;
}

.token-red {
    color: red;
}

.token-gray {
    color: gray;
}


